# How to count number of user gives rating to specific item in jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to count how many user have given rating to specific products. My code is working fine but it just don't store the number of times a item is rated. For example, it store that item with id `17` is rated `5` by one user, `4` by other user, `3` by other user and so on but it could not store the overall users like `3` user give rating on item with `17`.

Then, I initialize the count_rating variable with `0` and it get increment when any user click on rating. But still it shows count_rating for every product because may be I have put `count_rating=count_rating++`.

So, when the `onclick` function runs, it simply just increment the value.
It would be great if anyone look out my code and can edit my code.
All I want that once a user give rating to item with id `17`, it increment the count_rating 1 and if another user give rating to same product then count_rating get increment to `2`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.rating',function(){
    var count_rating=0;
    count_rating= count_rating+1;
    var index = $(this).data("index");
    var business_id = $(this).data('business_id');
    var username='<?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>';
    var useremail='<?php echo $_SESSION["useremail"];?>';
    $.ajax({
        url:"search_rating.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{index:index,business_id:business_id,username:username,useremail:useremail,count_rating:count_rating},
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data == 'done')
            {
                alert("Dear "+username+",You rate "+index+" out of 5 for this product");
            }
            else if(data == 'update')
            {
                alert("Dear "+username+",you updated your rating for this product");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Dear "+username+",Sorry but there is some problem in system");
            }
        }
    });
});

});
```

Comment: JavaScript is client-site you would need to collect these data on the server, preferably within some database.

Comment: Can you telll how can i collect the all data on server.In my server(XAMPP),it is storing that which item is rated by whom but it just not collect the all user data for specific item.

Comment: Just use some database engine, most probably MySQL as it's included in XAMPP. A more detailed answer will be possible if you'll implement any DB `INSERT` in your `search_rating.php` script.

Comment: yes,this script insert into search_rating

Comment: What i am thinking is that there should be additional code which can count rating with productid.but don't know how to do.Can you refer me some links where this kind of work is using.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:*** That, of course, is only POC, in real life your database structure, field types and other factors can differ, but this is something you should resolve yourself. This sample is tested and works as expected.

---

### Let's do it!

First using **PhpMyAdmin** of your XAMPP create an empty database for this case let's name it `test_ratings`, make sure it uses some UTf-8 charset, I suggest `utf8_general_ci` and add columns/index to it with this code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ratings (
 uid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 business_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 useremail varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 count_rating int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (uid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**Note**, as `index` is reserved keyword in MySQL/MariaDB I renamed it to `uid` so reflect it in your JavaScript as well.

So finally, everything you need is to connect with your DB, INSERT or UPDATE the row, and return the updated state to the user.

Your `search_rating.php` should work like this:

```php
<?php

// create a pdo object
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_ratings;charset=utf8", "yourusername", "yourpassword");
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Prepare INSERT/UPDATE query, bindValues, execute and get last inserted/updated uid
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    INSERT INTO ratings (uid, business_id, username, useremail, count_rating)
    VALUES (:uid, :business_id, :username, :useremail, :count_rating)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        username=:username, 
        business_id=:business_id, 
        useremail=:useremail, 
        count_rating=count_rating+:count_rating
");

$stmt->bindValue('uid',          $_POST['uid'],          PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('username',     $_POST['username'],     PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('business_id',  $_POST['business_id'],  PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue('useremail',    $_POST['useremail'],    PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue('count_rating', $_POST['count_rating'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$lastUid = $pdo->lastInsertId();

// Read updated value to return it to user
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT uid, count_rating FROM ratings where uid=:uid");
$res = $stmt->execute(['uid' => $lastUid]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo("Record {$row['uid']} has rating: {$row['count_rating']} now.");
```

**Note** that as an AJAX response I would return something better than echoing raw string, ie. a JSON object with more details and proper `CONTENT-TYPE`, however, it's already up to you.

Comment: Well, thank you ao much for your effort and looking uopn on my code. But, i resolved it by my self. I tried so manyntimea and end wirh solving it. What i did is i fetch the data feom db and put Count on rating and atore it in session and call it in jquery. Its worked for me.

Comment: @aleena Great that you are working on your own solutions instead of waiting for ready-to-use solutions. That's the best way, always. Just make sure you're using parameterised statements and good luck :)

Comment: @aleena, just let me understand, you fetch current rating for your product when the user opens the page, you store it in session and later when he clicks to rate it you get a current rating from the session, increase by 5 and store to the database?

Comment: first of all,thankx for appreciation.Actually,there is a product decription page which shows product details along with how many user give rating to that product to users.To show product details,i fetched the data from that particular product from its table and i also used COUNT(rating) as rating_num to show how many users give rating to that product.But the problem was that i did not knew that how can i store that Count value in db because i am inserting the value through jquer via call ajax.So,then i get the value of rating_num in session and used it jquery part.